# ASP.net why can't I access this web.config key?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

```
public partial class MasterPages_Main : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string TopMenuTab;
    public string SubMenuTab;
    public Configuration Config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContentMenu.TopTabSelected = TopMenuTab;
        ContentMenu.SubTabSelected = SubMenuTab;

        Response.Write("K" + Config.AppSettings.Settings["BlogCommentsPerPage"].ToString());
    }

}
```

In web.config:

```
<appSettings>

    <!-- Website settings -->
    <add key="BlogCommentsPerPage" value="3" />
```

I get:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

On the response.write line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var commentsPerPage = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["BlogCommentsPerPage"];
```

do a null check and then call `ToString()` or `Convert.ToInt32()`

Answer (score 1):

`ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings` is the correct approach.

You don't need the `Config` object. You only need to use `OpenWebConfiguration` if you're going to write to the `web.config` file. It isn't needed just to read the config data.

**Edit:** When any .Net application starts, its config file data is read into memory and cached there  for the lifetime of the app. The general assumption is that the config data will be used enough to warrant this use of memory, and that it will be worthwhile to avoid the cost of opening the file and reading the XML every time config information is needed by the app.